# Suggest ways to represent additive fixed effects?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, meta-analysis, fixed-effects-model

The dataset I'm working with has additive fixed effect where each term is significant. I want to plot the model fit with one of the factors `temp` here on the x-axis and the y.var in the y-axis.

I was made aware of a cool way of visualizing interactions of fixed effects in ggplot2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72274425/6820344). I tried to follow a similar recipe here and wondering if there are any other ways to visualize it?

```
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(geomtextpath)
library(lme4)


temp <- rnorm(100, 2,1)set.seed(111)
temp <- rnorm(100, 3,1)
rainfall <- rnorm(100,5,1)
y.var <- rnorm(100, 2,1)
site <- rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each = 25)     

df <- data.frame(temp, rainfall, y.var, site)
df$site <- as.factor(as.character(df$site))

mod <- lmer(y.var ~ temp + rainfall + (1|site), data  = df)
summary(mod) #Let's assume both temp and rainfall are significant

newdf <- expand.grid(temp = seq(min(df$temp), max(df$temp), length = 100),
                     rainfall = seq(min(df$rainfall), max(df$rainfall), 
                                    length = 5))

newdf$y.var <- predict(mod, newdata = newdf)

ggplot(newdf, aes(x = temp, y = y.var, group = rainfall)) +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(shape = site, color = rainfall)) +
  geom_textline(aes(color = rainfall, label = round(rainfall, 2)), 
                hjust = 0.95) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = 'navy', high = 'red4') +
  theme_light(base_size = 16)
```

[image]